# How to open custom url in a PWA on iOS 16.4

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

With the new features in WebKit 16.4 it is now possible to use Web Push on Apple devices. The function was quite easy to install. Unfortunately, however, I run into a problem. When I click on the notification, I want to go to a specific page within the Progressive Web App. This works fine in Chrome. In Safari, I always get to the home page of the PWA.

This is my used code within the ServiceWorker:

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {
    console.log('On notification click: ', event);

    event.waitUntil(
        clients.matchAll({
            type: 'window',
        })
            .then((clientList) => {
                for (const client of clientList) {
                    if (client.url === url && 'focus' in client) {
                        return client.focus();
                    }
                }
                return clients.openWindow('/calendar'); // does not work. It opens the url "/" instead of "/calendar"
            })
    );

    event.notification.close();
})
```

Also, I tried to give the notification from iOS multiple actions. These are not displayed at all. In Chrome it works.
[image]

[image]

I tried debugging it with a connected iPhone which runs on iOS 16 Public Beta and Safari Technology Preview which has the WebKit 16.4 changes integrated.

I would expect the notification actions to be displayed and a specific link within the PWA to be opened when clicking the notification or an action in the notification.

Are these two functions I use not yet implemented with iOS 16.4 ?  Maybe someone has an idea if or when this will be supported or if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. It might be a limitation of iOS 16.4 for now. The notification system seems very limited currently (as it only seems to support title and body). I thought about setting a cookie inside the service worker on `notificationclick` and reading it on the main-page (+ redirecting) but cookies and local storage don't seem to work inside the service worker.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that the showNotification options.actions parameter is not supported in iOS Safari, according to the Browser Compatibility table in the showNotification article in MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/showNotification#browser_compatibility

Comment: You could use IndexedDB instead of cookies or local storage. I have the same issue and think I will go this way.

Comment: This might me a good workaround, yes!