# Are iOS/iPad OS PWA notifications working as intended?

Tags: ios, safari, progressive-web-apps

Apple have finally brought in support for Push and Notifications APIs to PWAs pinned to homescreen on iOS/iPadOS which is great news. I've had a draft implementation built up for our PWA for sometime but now that we're able to test with Apple devices we're encountering some unexpected behaviours.

1. After the 3rd push received without triggering a notification your device's subscription is terminated.

Typically we'd be able to do focus detection on the client's service worker to work out whether the  PWA is open and in use and handle the notification in app instead of firing off a notification. I can see the logic for saving on data usage and battery drain on silent notifications when the PWA is closed but this seems excessive if you’ve got the PWA open and in focus already.

2. After installing the PWA to the device's homescreen and opting to receive notifications clicking through a notification doesn't seem to reliably trigger the 'notificationclicked' event. So the notification is removed from the screen but the all important URL or data payload isn't processed.

Closing the PWA fully and opening the app up again after another notification seems to fix this but it's not really a workable solution for potential users. This behaviour does seem to be fairly inconsistent but I was able to replicate it on a 3rd party's online PWA demo (this is a pretty barebones implementation): https://simple-push-demo.vercel.app. Have also stumbled across a [similar question on this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75792142/how-to-open-custom-url-in-a-pwa-on-ios-16-4) but with as yet no responses

3. Web notifications don't currently appear to have the ability to trigger alert sounds or haptic patterns either.

I'm sure my PWA's current implementation is far from perfect but being able to replicate these issues elsewhere in other PWAs may suggest that there could be some quirks to Apple's implementation.

Anyone else out there running into any of the above or other issues with these so far? Are these are known issues and are there known work arounds at present?

Have stripped back our implementation to the bare minimum required by the standards and still issues persist. Have even replicated encountered problem on other demo PWAs online.

Comment: I'm seeing similar issues, as well as not receiving notifications if the app has been swiped closed (regardless of the state of the device -- on the home screen, on the lock screen, asleep).